# Linq to Entities Select clause with lambda

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am working on a new project and we are using Entity Framework and the dev lead would like to use lambda queries whenever possible.  One thing we are having a hard time figuring out is how to select two columns specifically.  Also how to select distinct.  We have a table that has multiple entries for a vendor but we want to just get a list of vendors and load to a dictionary object.  It fails because as written it is trying to add a key value that has already been added.  Take the following query.

```
Dictionary<int, string> dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        dict = GetWamVendorInfo().AsEnumerable()
                    .Where(x => x.vendor_name != null && x.vendor_id != null)
                    //.Select(x => x.vendor_id).Distinct()
                    .Take(2)
                    .ToDictionary(o => int.Parse(o.vendor_id.ToString()), o => o.vendor_name);
```

What I would like to do is select just vendor_id and vendor_name so we can get just the distinct records.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Rhonda

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use an anonymous type:

```
// earlier bit of query
.Select(x => new { VendorId = x.vendor_id, VendorName = x.vendor_name } )
.Distinct()
.ToDictionary(o => o.VendorId, o => o.VendorName);
```

I've removed the call to `Take(2)` as it wasn't clear why you'd want it - and also removed the parsing of `VendorId`, which I would have expected to already be an integer type.

Note that you should almost *certainly* remove the `AsEnumerable` call from your query - currently you'll be fetching *all* the vendors and filtering with LINQ to Objects. There's also no point creating an empty dictionary and then ignoring it entirely. I suspect your complete query should be:

```
var vendors = GetWamVendorInfo()
                      .Select(x => new { VendorId = x.vendor_id,
                                         VendorName = x.vendor_name } )
                      .Distinct()
                      .ToDictionary(o => o.VendorId,
                                    o => o.VendorName);
```

As an aside, you should ask your dev lead *why* he wants to use lambda expressions (presumably as opposed to query expressions) everywhere. Different situations end up with more readable code using different syntax options - it's worth being flexible on this front.

Comment: I just had the take(2) out to test what I had because I knew the first two had different keys.

Comment: .Distinct seems to still not be working as I am getting mulitple records with the same vendorId.  I guess I should also mention that vendorId is not the primary key for this table so there are some that are null and some that are duplicates (why I need to select distinct).  Also the vendorId is a long.

Comment: @Rhonda: It's only going to be distinct by *all the properties* - in other words, if you've got two records with the same ID but different names, they're distinct so will both be returned. If the vendor ID is a long, why are you converting it to an int? Why not just leave it as a long?

Comment: That conversion was probably just a result of trying multiple things to get the dropdown list to display the correct values.  It seems to work just fine as a long.

Comment: As it turns out.  The entegrity of the data we are trying to use is crap.  Lot's of vendors have the same id but the name is slightly different depending on what system it was pulled from.  That has to be addressed first.  Then the code will work.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6):

Just use an anonymous object:

```
var vendors = GetWamVendorInfo().AsEnumerable()
                .Where(x => x.vendor_name != null && x.vendor_id != null)
                .Select(new {x.vendor_id, x.vendor_name})
                .Take(2)
```

That's it.  You can now work with `vendors[0].vendor_id`, `vendors[0].vendor_name`, and so on.