# how to get student courses with entity framework

Tags: entity-framework

I have 2 classes, course and student, and I want to get student courses with student id
help me please

I'm using entity framework code first

```
public class Course {
    public int CourseID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Details { get; set; }
    public string img { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
    public Guid UserAddID { get; set; }
    public Guid userEditID { get; set; }
    public int SubCategoryID { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Summury { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public bool IsGift { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateUpdated { get; set; }
    public bool DelFlag { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DelDate { get; set; }
    public Guid? UserDelID { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}


public class Student {
   [Key]
   public int StudentID { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public DateTime? DateBirth { get; set; }
   public int? Age { get; set; }
   public int? Sex { get; set; }
   public string Email { get; set; }
   public string Phone { get; set; }
   public string Mobile { get; set; }
   public string Mobile2 { get; set; }
   public string UniversityID { get; set; }
   public string CollegeID { get; set; }
   public string IdentityID { get; set; }
   public string Address { get; set; }
   public string Education { get; set; }
   public decimal? Payments { get; set; }
   public string HowToKnow { get; set; }
   public DateTime? GradeDate { get; set; }
   public string LaterCourses { get; set; }
   public string Job { get; set; }
   public string Specialist { get; set; }
   public string Notes { get; set; }
   public int StatueID { get; set; }
   public Guid? UserID { get; set; }
   public DateTime? DateAdded { get; set; }
   public Guid UserAddID { get; set; }
   public Guid userEditID { get; set; }
   public DateTime DateUpdated { get; set; }
   public bool DelFlag { get; set; }
   public DateTime? DelDate { get; set; }
   public Guid? UserDelID { get; set; }
   public virtual IList<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}
```

I want to get all courses for a given StudentID using a lambda expression.

Comment: That's not lambda syntax. Did you search and try to make it work going off something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286328/linq-to-entities-select-clause-with-lambda)?

Comment: i wrote something similar to clearing isue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var students = repository.Query<Course>(c => c.Student.Any(st=>st.StudentID == StudentID)
```